# how to implement dash video streaming of jwplayer in android

Tags: android, jwplayer

I have a jwplayer account and i have uploaded some videos there.

Now i want to add quality changing button and also want to make player to choose video quality based on internet. But how to do that

xml file :-

```
<com.longtailvideo.jwplayer.JWPlayerView xmlns:jwp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.longtailvideo.jwplayer"
            android:id="@+id/jwplayer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

java file:-

```
mPlayerView = findViewById(R.id.jwplayer);
        PlaylistItem playlistItem = new PlaylistItem.Builder()
                .file("https://content.jwplatform.com/videos/k6Jle9TB-Ruucf9kn.mp4")
                .image("https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/mountains-during-sunset-beautiful-natural-260nw-407021107.jpg")
                .title("Playlist-Item Title")
                .description("Some really great content")
                .build();

        RelatedConfig related = new RelatedConfig.Builder()
                .file("https://content.jwplatform.com/videos/IHToMSjV-Ruucf9kn.mp4")
                .autoPlayTimer(5)
                .onComplete(RELATED_ON_COMPLETE_AUTOPLAY)
                .autoPlayMessage("new video will begin in 10 seconds")
                .build();

        List<PlaylistItem> playlist = new ArrayList<>();
        playlist.add(playlistItem);
        PlayerConfig config = new PlayerConfig.Builder()
                .playlist(playlist)
                .relatedConfig(related)
                .build();
        mPlayerView.setup(config);
```

I also want to live stream the video So i came up with DASH which has no documentation on jwplayer docs.
So where to start please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be pointing directly to the MP4 assets on the JW platform. You should be taking advantage of their Delivery API and have an object form the platform with all of the relevant data - https://cdn.jwplayer.com/v2/media/k6Jle9TB

Also, having JW create a DASH manifest for you would require an Enterprise contract. It is of little benefit to you now, so stick with the M3U8 (HLS) manifest they give you in the feed I linked to above.